# Java user agent parser

Tags: java, user-agent

I was searching for a good Java USerAgent parser and I found http://user-agent-utils.java.net/

How can I test it to see if I get the correct results?

Answer (score 6):

You can get a look at [UADetector](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net), it seems better supported than user-agent-utils (up to date parser, actively developed, monthly releases)

Comment: Looks like this library doesnt provide version of any browser from user agent value.

Comment: @Nandakishore The UserAgent class does have a method returning the version though http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/modules/uadetector-core/apidocs/net/sf/uadetector/UserAgent.html#getVersionNumber()

Answer (score 1):

One of they official tests can be seen [here](http://code.google.com/p/user-agent-utils/source/browse/trunk/UserAgentUtils/src/test/java/nl/bitwalker/useragentutils/BrowserTest.java?spec=svn113&r=113)

Comment: is there any way I ca test it on my own??