# user agent parser

Tags: java, parsing, user-agent

I have a user agent:
`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)`

I am using `nl.bitwalker` (http://user-agent-utils.java.net/) as a library in order to parse information from the user agent.

The problem is that I don't know how to use `nl.bitwalker` to get the information I want.

If you know please let me know.

[EDITED] How can I get the device type using this library??

Comment: What information do you want?

Comment: Please complete your (simular) previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659508/java-user-agent-parser

Comment: how can I remove the other one??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's seems simple to use from the Javadoc

```
UserAgent agent = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(userAgentString);
Browser browser = agent.getBrowser();
Version version = agent.getBrowserVersion();
OperatingSystem os = agent.getOperatingSystem();
```

What do you need if it's not that ?

Comment: thank you, i need to parse the information in a way that I could use those information to create mobile device statistics, (pie chart), Also is this all the info you can parse from the user agent???

Comment: from the `UserAgent` class, yes, that's all. But after, you got plenty of information from the other Classes. From `Browser`, you get the rendering engine, the manufacturer, the name, the group, etc

Comment: I need basically all the inforamtion you can extract from a log file, I need the device version, type browser, everything